# How do I use the outputs from a Cox Proportional Hazard model in R (with time-dependent covariates) to make user-level forecasts?

Tags: r, intervals, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a pretty standard survival analysis set-up with right-censoring, and tracking users at regular time intervals measured from a relative t=0 time.

I have two static covariates X1 and X2, but one time-dependent covariate X3 measured at each interval, AKA interval-censored data.

Here's some dummy data for 6 individuals in long format where the X3 feature is split into multiple columns, one for each period.

```
library(survival)
library(MASS)
library(data.table)

dt.wide <-
  data.table("id" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
             "time" = c(5, 4, 3, 9, 1, 8),
             "status" = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
             "X1" = c(52, 59, 54, 60, 39, 26),
             "X2" = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
             "X3.1" = c(21, 17, 17, 23, 26, 19),
             "X3.2" = c(18, 13, 15, 19, NA, 14),
             "X3.3" = c(16, 22, 17, 17, NA, 20),
             "X3.4" = c(19, 13, NA, 20, NA, 15),
             "X3.5" = c(25, NA, NA, 19, NA, 20),
             "X3.6" = c(NA, NA, NA, 19, NA, 20),
             "X3.7" = c(NA, NA, NA, 16, NA, 22),
             "X3.8" = c(NA, NA, NA, 13, NA, 20),
             "X3.9" = c(NA, NA, NA, 23, NA, NA))
```

Based on this [paper](https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Cox-Regression.pdf), section 4 provides details on how to deal with this type of data and incorporate the time-dependency, essentially changing this from right -censoring one row per user to multiple rows per user and interval censoring.

The new data in long format now is:

```
dt.long <-
  data.table("id"    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
                         4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6),
             "start" = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                         6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
             "stop"  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                         7, 8, 9, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
             "event" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
             "X1"    = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 59, 59, 59, 59, 54, 54, 54, 60,
                         60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 39, 26, 26, 26, 26,
                         26, 26, 26, 26),
             "X2"    = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
             "X3"    = c(21, 18, 16, 19, 25, 17, 13, 22, 13, 17, 15, 17, 23,
                         19, 17, 20, 19, 19, 16, 13, 23, 26, 19, 14, 20, 15,
                         20, 20, 22, 20))
```

The Cox Proportional hazard model is now run:

```
cph.model <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, event) ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = dt.long)
```

My question now is how to get the predictions for a new user.
For instance, assume the new data is for a the following user who is currently in interval 6-7:

```
nd <- data.table("id"    = 7,
                 "start" = 6,
                 "stop"  = 7,
                 "X1"    = 30,
                 "X2"    = 1,
                 "X3"    = 20)
```

I would like to know their probability of surviving the next periods, and ultimately compute their expected number of future periods until death/event occurs (expected lifetime is the AOC of the survival curve from there on out).

Getting predictions can be done via:

```
sf <- survfit(cph.model, newdata = nd)
times <- sf[["time"]]
prob.mat <- t(sf[["surv"]])
```

and prob.mat output for this new user is:

```
    [,1] [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]
[1,]   1    1 0.84815 0.69705 0.53001 0.53001 0.53001 0.27879 0.27879
```

These values do not change when I modify the `"start"` and `"stop"` values in `nd`, leading me to believe that the model is ignoring the fact that I know this user has made it all the way to period 6-7. I could normalize the relative values by normalizing the absolute survival curve in prob.mat:

S(surviving 7-8 | surviving 6-7) = S(surviving 7-8) / S(surviving 6-7)

But the bigger issue is that the model is ignoring the fact that the X3 value of 20 is for period 6-7 and not a static value such as X1 or X2.

In other words, feeding the following data:

```
nd <- data.table("id"    = 7,
                 "start" = 3,
                 "stop"  = 4,
                 "X1"    = 30,
                 "X2"    = 1,
                 "X3"    = 20)
```

should yield a different prob.mat as the value of X3=20 now applies to the 3-4 period, but the same prob.mat is returned.

Back to the original question: based on the available data in `1dt.wide1` or `1dt.long1`, how can I get for a new user in the middle of their journey the expectation of remaining periods to go before death/event?

Comment: The reason the survival package will not offer you a `predict` method for new instances of interval censored data is that the survival package's author, arguably the world's leading authority on such matters, believes that it should not be done. My summary of what I have read regarding his reasoning: If the history of covariates matters, then the estimates would only apply to someone with the same history. (And I think this may be a duplicate question.)

Comment: My efforts to find a duplicate have failed. Perhaps I am thinking of threads in the R-help mailing list or possibly this is something I commented on and SO's search function isn't looking at comments? I did find my own answer to a question about predictions in the right-censored situation which the cited paper appears to not cover.

Comment: A further idea. Could you instead calculate a total exposure by taking the predictor covariate value and multiplying it by the number of time units over which it would have been acting on each individual and use that instead of the time-dependent model? Seems like it would be in line with how long-term exposures to environmental agents are often modeled. For example smoking is modeled as pack-years. You might lose information about high dose rates for brief intervals if there were some sort of threshold effect.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, apologies for the delayed response! I will try to look up your reference as to why the author believes "it should not be done". I feel there are many situations where this would be of value and do-able...

Comment: I'll have to think more about your other suggestion. My alternative approach was to build multiple right-censored models (one for each time period basically). Way more models to maintain, but it would remove the time-dependency component and make predictions easier.
Thanks again for all your help/thoughts!

Comment: I suspect that a proper analysis will need to be constructed using information about the type of exposure that X3 represents. To continue with a biological example, namely smoking exposure, there is very probably a lag period before any given exposure has its full effects. So my earlier suggestion of using pack years would over-simplify that sort of exposure-outcome relationship. Smoking heavily  age 20 to 40 versus smoking heavily  ages 40 to 60 might well have a different effect for a person over the interval age 60 to 65, because the genetic damage would have had longer to manifest.

Comment: So I suggest asking over at CrossValidated.com and including more about the "grounding" of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your edit suggestions and additional thoughts! In my particular case, X3 would be relatively instantaneous: level of X3 in period P will have a large impact on whether the event is observed in P+1.
Even if there was a cumulative effect as in smoking, I'm guessing one could replace X3 by the cumulative X3 to take the build-up effect into account?